# C# Tree view similar

Tags: gui-construction

Is it possible in Mathematica to add a GUI like the Tree GUI element in Visual Studio 2010 C# Windows Forms?
I want to have the similar feel

[image]

Comment: Use Wolfram Workbench

Comment: Does [`OpenerView`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenerView.html) do what you want?

Comment: No it doesn't look like what I want

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK there is no ready to use functionality for this in Mathematica available at this time.

I see two possibilities to still get what you want: either use `NETLink` or `JLink` to write a GUI containing a treeview supplied by either `.NET` or e.g. `Swing`. That will mean your GUI will have to live in an extra window, will need some deeper understanding of the underlying non-Mathematica GUI functionality and will not run in the free CDF-Player.

If you want to stay within Mathematica, your best bet is to use a combination of `OpenerView` and `Column` as Verbeia suggested to achieve something that behaves a lot like the Windows TreeView but of course does not look exactly like one. Here is an example:

```
Module[{c}, Panel[{
     "Food" -> {
       "Fruits" -> {"Apple", "Peach"},
      "Vegetables" -> {"Tomato", "Eggplant"}
      },
     "Drinks" -> {
       "Softdrink" -> {"Coke"},
       "Alcoholic" -> {"Beer", "Wine"}
     }
   } //. {
    list : {__String} :> c @@ list,
    list : {__Rule} :> c @@ (OpenerView[{#1, #2}] & @@@ list)
  } /. c :> Function[Column[{##}]]
]]
```

of course there are a lot of other possibilities to implement that and you might want to put some more effort to improve various aspects, e.g. with wrapping it with a `Pane` with some scrollbars, some more obvious indentation for the leaves and some interactivity for the nodes with `Button` or `PopupMenu`. But the basic idea to combine `OpenerView` and `Column` or probably `Grid` probably won't change very much. When using `PaneSelector` instead of `OpenerView` you would have some more control over the visual appearance, but I doubt you can get it to look exactly like the Windows TreeView, especially the lines visualizing the tree connections would probably be very difficult to build.

Comment: The example is useless because the small lines connecting the nodes are missing and the nodes alignment is confusing also , not like in the C# window

Comment: @timoftebogdan I think if you search for people to help you you should show at least a minimal amount of politeness and the effort to read what these people write. I have explicitly mentioned that it does not look like the the windows treeview and that I think that it would be very much effort to make it look like that. As it does provide the basic **functionality** I personaly (and probably other readers) think it is far from useless. If you need it to look exactly like the windows TreeView the answer is probably as short as "not possible" (also already contained in my answer).

Comment: I used TreePlot with Left so its on his side , and I think your example is worse than TreePlot: